# Chrome Custom Tab get content and page event listener

Tags: javascript, android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm developing an Android app. In past projects, I used to use WebView to show web content. This gave me the capability to intercept events like page loaded and so on. The important thing that I was able to do was to get page content and use it in the Java code. To be honest, I use a trick, but it works. I put the essential code of my fragment to use a WebView to open an URL, do something and when the user arrives in a specific page and get the page content (with `MyJavaScriptInterface`):

```java
public class LoginFragment extends MyAppFragment {

    @BindView(R.id.webView)
    public WebView webView;


    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        initBinder(rootView);
        ...
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);


        /* Register a new JavaScript interface called HTMLOUT */
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        webView.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.url_login).trim());

        return rootView;
    }

    /* An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface */
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(String token) {
            if (token.contains(URL_LANDING)) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    private WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Logger.info("shouldInterceptRequest " + request.getUrl().toString());
            if (URL_LANDING_SESAPP.equals(request.getUrl().toString())) {
              ...  
            } 
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            ...
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            ...
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            ...
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            pageLoading = false;

            if (loginDone) {
 view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);")
            } 
        }

    };

}
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this with Chrome Custom Tags? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some of them are possible with passing ```CustomTabsCallback``` when creating a new session.

Comment: Hi xcesco, Do we have any update on using Java Script Interface with the custom tabs?